# Reading string from a text file to build a binary search tree?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Is there any source code for me as reference. I'm studying a binary search tree. thanks

Comment: [Building a balanced binary search tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893318/building-a-balanced-binary-search-tree) -> Replace the integer comparison with string compare after reading the file's words into a string list.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Section 3 of the following link:

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html

Linux implementation of the tree is accessible here:

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/include/linux/btree.h

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the functions of [stdio.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/). Then you can read on [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) to learn how to make it. You'll find lots of examples in the above links.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a Binary tree implementation in C here:

http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/tree.html

And you can read about how to read from text files in C here:

http://www.mrx.net/c/readfunctions.html

Simply, while using this implementation, read from your file and use the appropriate method to add a node to your tree.