# Convert (un)sorted array to binary search tree in c

Tags: c

I have been looking this for hours but i can not find a code which i want.

```
for example array is : 45 16 22 51 18 72 33 64 40

binary must be : 45 16 0 22 0 72 0 0 18 33 0 0 64 0 0 0 0
```

It puts according to `2n+1` and `2n+2` but i do not know how to do this in code. Should i use pop and push?

```
                45
          16           51
       22                 72
   18     33           64
            40
```

Comment: *Hint*: look up a binary heap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893318/building-a-balanced-binary-search-tree

Comment: Your diagram of the tree is not correct.

Comment: You've lost `51` in your 'binary must be' list.  Which makes it kinda hard to know what is really required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the given array is a[n] and b[MAX] be the binary trees array then the algorithm can be like this,

```
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
 b[i]=-1;
b[0]=a[0];
j=0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
lable1:
 if(b[j]<a[i])
 {
  k=2j+2;
 }
 else
 {
  k=2j+1;
 }
 if(b[k]==-1)
 {
  b[k]=a[i];
  j=0;
 }
 else
 {
  j=k;
  goto: lable1
 }
}
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
if(b[i]==-1)
 b[i]=0;
```

at the end replace all positions with -1 value to 0 to complete the binary tree representation. this code is just to give idea about how you can implement it. i used -1 to indicate empty location. you can use any special value that may not come as input. and MAX value is binary tree size that you can compute, given n.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm can be as follows.

```
First convert the unsorted array into a sorted one.
```

Now with the sorted array, do the following:

```
Return if all elements are inserted.
Pick the middle element (cur_index). Create a node with it.
Call left from left_index to (cur_index-1).
Call right from to (cur_index+1) to right_index.
```